# Handling errors and continuing execution in PHP script

Tags: php, execution, die

I don't want to "die()" when it concerns only a small part of the script and I tried:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or echo("error with responses");
```

But it generated an error. How do I just give out an error message and continue to execute the rest of the script since even if it fails to connect, the rest should not be affected.

Comment: The question title nearly gave me an aneurysm.

Comment: See, now that's a title to get views/responses. Generally only a fatal error (often, syntax errors and the like) should kill a script. What was the specific error message you got?

Comment: actually, it's funny, I didn't pay attention to my title after I looked at the list of questions asked and then I asked. lol I didn't want to terminate the script just because of a mysql error. I wanted to keep executing the rest of the script even if it fails to get data from db.

Comment: I've updated the title, as the previous one seemed (at best) irrelevant. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_error()) {
  echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: @netrox So accept this answer, your accept ratio will be higher.

Comment: im waiting for 10 minutes to expire :/

Answer (score 5):

In terms of your original question title - you can't. The purpose of `die` and `exit` are to terminate script processing. If you don't want to terminate script processing, don't call `die` or `exit`.

In terms of suppressing the output of errors, this is possible using the [error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) (`@`) but in-advisable. (You ***must*** check for error state yourself if you're suppressing errors in this manner.)

For example, you could use:

```
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
if(is_resource($result)) {
    // The query worked...

}
else {
   // Handle error state, perhaps using mysql_error
}
```

However, just to make this clear, ***NEVER*** casually add the error suppressor to a function call. You ***MUST*** ensure you're handling any potential errors correctly yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or print("error with responses");
```

Echo cannot be used in logical comparisons such as what you're trying to do. You should use print instead, that won't cause PHP errors.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return type of mysql_query

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result===false) {

 echo 'The Query failed';
}

//> Continue
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `die` as the second function call, it's just used as a convention in almost every `mysql_query` tutorial out there.

All we're doing is evaluating a boolean expression.  `$result = $a OR $b`.  If the value of `$a` is true, then we never execute `$b` because we don't need to.  We've satisfied the logical `OR` with one side of the operator being true, which is all we need.

The [die()](http://php.net/die) function immediately exits the script with a message.  You could replace it with your own function to print a pretty error message and continue through the script without exiting., e.g:

```
function my_error_function($status) {
    echo "ERROR: $status";
}

$result = mysql_query($sql) or my_error_function("Uhoh.  There was a problem executing $sql.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off error reporting, which you want to do anyway in a production environment.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

It will still throw an error, but it will no longer be shown.

This is very unusual, though. I can't think of a reason why one would want to accept a mySQL error - if the problem is broken SQL, you would usually catch it beforehand.

Comment: MySQL errors can be good - if you get a duplicate key error, for example, you'd present the user with a message that their username/URL/whatever already exists and continue on.

Comment: @ceejayoz I would tend to want to catch that beforehand. I don't like showing raw SQL error messages to end users, not even if the server is unreachable.

Comment: You don't have to show the raw error message. Use `mysql_errno()` to figure out what the error was, then handle it.

Comment: @ceejayoz yeah, then we're on the same page. I thought you meant passing errors through directly to the user

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at **try** / **catch** not die() or exit

Comment: Alas, the decrepit mysql extension doesn't throw exceptions, so there's nothing to try/catch.  This'd be correct if PDO was being used.

Comment: @charles: yet another reason to use a wrapper layer to make it throw exceptions, or use errorexceptions.  So there are ways to make it work...